# NoSQL write-once, automatic timestamp indexed

Tags: database, nosql

I'm looking for the least-effort solution to store data in a database. Here are the requirements:

- this will be the storage backend for a test automation tool
- data will be messages captured from queues: can be JSON, XML, binary... but could be converted to a uniform representation
- data will be written once, whatever is written will not change
- there will be multiple indexes necessary, however the base index should be the timestamp of the messages inserted into the database - it would be nice if the database of choice could be configured to provide this automatically (eg. query messages inserted between two timestamps - should work out of the box)
- ease of query is important (SQL would be best, however the structure of the messages is not always known in advance)
- performance is not important
- fault tolerance, partition tolerance, reliability etc are not important
- ease of access (eg. REST API, API from multiple platforms - JVM, JS, etc) is important.

I was looking at MongoDB, CouchDB, maybe Riak... All of these could work, I just don't know which is the least resistance for the requirements above. I am familiar with Riak, but its strengths are not really what I'm after...

Comment: This is really broad and opinion-soliciting. There simply is no way to answer this question, aside from having a conversation about it. Not a fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

@geraldss has addressed the INSERT question. Let me add the example.

1. Indexing: you can create indices one one or more fields and the query will use them automatically.
   create index idx_ins_time on my_bucket(insert_time);
   select my_message from my_bucket 
      where insert_time 
     between "2016-04-03T10:46:33.857-07:00" and "2016-04-05T10:46:33.857-07:00";
   Use EXPLAIN to see the plan, just like SQL.
2. You can create multiple indices with one or more keys each.
3. Couchbase N1QL supports REST API, JDBC/ODBC and SDKs for most popular languages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CouchBase is the best alternative, simply because N1QL:
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-intro/data-access-using-n1ql.html

It ticks all the other boxes (except for the automatic timestamp indexes, but then adding that and doing range queries is straightforward thanks to the query language).

Comment: Sorry, but just stating CouchBase is the best alternative... doesn't make it the best alternative.

Comment: David, do you have anything constructive to add?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Couchbase, you can use N1QL's INSERT statement to automatically add the timestamp:

```
INSERT INTO my_bucket(KEY, VALUE)
VALUES ($my_key, {
    "insert_time": NOW_STR(),
    __my other data fields__
 }
)
```